# About assigning value to variables in Python

Tags: python

Here I wrote two simple programs and expected the results to be same:
program 1(result=123):

```
price=[]
def checkCondition(a,b):
    if a<b:
        price.append(123)
if  __name__ == '__main__':
    checkCondition(1,2)
print price[0]
```

program 2(result=''):

```
price=''
def checkCondition(a,b):
    if a<b:
        price=123
if  __name__ == '__main__':
    checkCondition(1,2)
print price
```

Why it couldn't assign 123 to price in program 2?

Comment: These are not the same operation at all. In the first you are mutating an object, in the second you are reassigning something.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: I disagree,it's not a dupe since there's no parameter at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning a local variable. Tell Python to use the global variable instead:

```
price=''
def checkCondition(a,b):
    global price # now reassigning price
    if a<b:
        price=123
if  __name__ == '__main__':
    checkCondition(1,2)
print price
```

From the Python doc [Naming and binding](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding):

> If a name binding operation occurs anywhere within a code block, all uses of the name within the block are treated as references to the current block. [...]
>
> If the global statement occurs within a block, all uses of the name specified in the statement refer to the binding of that name in the top-level namespace.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of python variables: globals and locals. Globals are reachable from all positions in your code. But locals are only reachable from the def() - definition they were created from. By default variables you create in a function are local and so there is a global price (='') amd a local price in your function(=123). To make it global and replace the existing global variable with the new one type on the beginning of your function definition:

```
global price
```

This makes the price variable in your functuon global.

The first one worked because your were not making a local variable. You did something on an existing variable (price). If the existing variable is global or not is not important then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the interpreter that you are referring to global name, as names inside functions are local to their scope by default:

```
price=''
def checkCondition(a,b):
    global price
    if a<b:
        price=123
if  __name__ == '__main__':
    checkCondition(1,2)
print price
```

Answer (score -1):

Note that inside a function, you can use a global variable, but can't change it without declaring it with `global` (see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement)).

The quote in the doc that matters:

> It would be impossible to assign to a global variable without global, although free variables may refer to globals without being declared global.

The first program used the variable by calling a method, which is okay and it `price` resolves to the global variable. For the second you intended to change a global variable's value, which isn't doable unless the variable is declared with `global`. Since you can't change the global variable's value, it will create a new local variable and assign the value to it.

To fix it, you need to use `global` to declare it first:

```
price=[]
def checkCondition(a,b):
    global price
    if a<b:
        price.append(123) # also works without the global
        price = 123
if  __name__ == '__main__':
    checkCondition(1,2)
print price
```